# nginx redirect to a subdomain even without trailing slashes

Tags: web-server, nginx, mod-rewrite, rewrite

I just installed and partially configured nginx on a dedicated server of mine. But I've got some trouble understanding the regexp. I would like to make nginx redirect www.mydomain.com/forum/ AND www.mydomain.com/forum (note the missing trailing slash; case-insensitive; same applies for "forums" instead of "forum") to forum.mydomain.com/. This is what I came up with:

`location ~* ^/(forum|forums) {

    rewrite ^/(.*)/(.*)$ http://forum.mydomain.com/$2? permanent;

}`

... but for some reason it works with trailing slashes only. :-/

Please help me! Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try:

```
location ~* ^/(forum|forums)/? {
   rewrite ^/(.*)/(.*)$ http://forum.mydomain.com/$2? permanent;
}
```

**EDIT:**

Ok the location seems to be working, the problem is probably the rewrite line.

```
location ~* ^/forums?/?$ {
   rewrite /forums?/?(.*) http://forum.mydomain.com/$1 permanent;
}
```

Tested the regex on `pcretest` and it captured it right, see if it works.

Comment: Thanks for your reply. However this didn't fix the problem :-(

Comment: Can you provide example URLS (original and how it should end)

Comment: See my initial post: hxxp://www.mydomain.com/forum (please note the missing trailing slash) -> hxxp://forum.mydomain.com/, but still hxxp://www.mydomain.com/forum/foo.bar?a=b -> hxxp://forum.mydomain.com/foo.bar?a=b (replace xx with tt, trying to bypass serverfault.com's limitations here :-P)

Comment: Thanks a lot!!!  
`location ~* ^/(forum|forums)?/?$ {  
    rewrite /(.*)?/?(.*) http://forum.mydomain.com/$2 permanent;  
}`  
works like a charm!

Comment: @oliver wait, what? :P

Comment: Two question marks make the regex work somehow. One wasn't enough... got to learn the PCRE regex syntax :-/

Comment: ... or maybe it was the dollar sign?

Comment: Curses! hxxp://www.mydomain.com/forum/foo.bar?a=b -> hxxp://forum.mydomain.com/foo.bar?a=b doesn't seem to work anymore... it just chops /foo.bar?a=b off

Comment: AH sorry, try the second form without the dollar sign in the end of the `location` line